# Turn column into multiple columns based on number of commas within string python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the below.

Focus on column 9. I'd like to turn each string that comes after a comma into a new column. So in Column 9, row 4, 'Ca., Cal.' I'd like 'Ca.' to remain in column 9 and 'Cal.' to go int column 10.

So ideal output for this (for select rows with multiple  commas)

```
      9      10     11    12
1    Alas.
4    Ca.     Cal.
13   Il.     Ills.  Ill
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic case for `izip_longest`, operating on column 9 as Series. You just need another transpose in the end, since you want to put them on rows.

```
from itertools import izip_longest
new_cols = DataFrame(list(izip_longest(*df[9].apply(lambda x:x.split(",")), fillvalue=""))).T
```

Then just add the new columns to your DataFrame.

Comment: This is great thanks! can you say alittle more about how izip_longest works?

Comment: They both transpose lists, so you get a list with the first value of each list, then a list with the second value of each list, and so on. `izip` would truncate all lists to the length of the shortest, izip_longest adds `fillvalue`s to match the length of the longest.